# ¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'tuple'?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

En el desarrollo de un programa, necesito implementar la estrategia que se muestra en las sentencias del siguiente script.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Creación del DataFrame
num_days = 1000

dates = pd.date_range('20160104', periods=1000, freq='D')
datos1 = pd.DataFrame(dates ,columns=['Date'])
datos2 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['High'])
datos3 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Low'])
datos4 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)), columns=['Close'])
datos5 = pd.DataFrame((np.random.randn(num_days) + np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.2, size=num_days)) ,columns=['Volume'])

datos = pd.concat([datos1,datos2,datos3,datos4, datos5],axis=1)
datos['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(datos['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
datos.set_index("Date", inplace = True)

# Implementación de una estrategia
EMAslow = 200
EMAfast = 100

datos['EMA100'] = datos['Close'].ewm(EMAfast, min_periods=4, adjust=True).mean()
datos['EMA200'] = datos['Close'].ewm(EMAslow, min_periods=4, adjust=True).mean()

for i in range(1, datos.shape[0]):
    # Our trading condition:
    long_positions = np.where ( datos.loc[i-1, 'EMA100'] <  datos.loc[i-1, 'EMA200']) & (datos.loc[i, 'EMA100'] >  datos.loc[i, 'EMA200'],1, 0)
    datos['Position'] = long_positions
    datos.round(3)        

datos [:3]
```

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
25 for i in range(1, datos.shape[0]):
26     # Our trading condition:
---> 27     long_positions = np.where ( datos.loc[i-1, 'EMA100'] <  datos.loc[i-1, 'EMA200']) & (datos.loc[i, 'EMA100'] >  datos.loc[i, 'EMA200'],1, 0)
28     datos['Position'] = long_positions
29     datos.round(3)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

¿Cuál puede ser la causa?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes DOS errores.
Al ejecutar el código tal y como lo tienes ahora, el parámetro `'condiciones'` de la instrucción `'np.where'`, debe ir entre paréntesis. Tú lo tienes así:

```
long_positions = np.where ( datos.loc[i-1, 'EMA100'] <  datos.loc[i-1, 'EMA200']) & (datos.loc[i, 'EMA100'] >  datos.loc[i, 'EMA200'],1, 0)
```

cuando debería ser así:

```
long_positions = np.where((datos.loc[i-1,'EMA100']<datos.loc[i-1,'EMA200'])&(datos.loc[i, 'EMA100']>datos.loc[i, 'EMA200']),1,0)
```

Te lo resumo para que lo veas más claro:
lo tienes así:

```
long_positions = np.where ( a <  b) & (c >  d,1, 0)
```

y debe ser así:

```
long_positions = np.where (( a <  b) & (c >  d),1, 0)
```

Una vez resuelto esto, te dará un error `'raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 0'`
Esto es porque usas `'datos.loc[i-1, 'EMA100']'` y le pasas como argumento de fila un entero, que se supone que es el valor del índice, pero tu índice es una fecha. Para resolverlo tienes que eliminar esta línea de tu código:

```
datos.set_index("Date", inplace = True)
```